# Си. Вычисление суммы натуральных чисел циклом for

Tags: c, циклы, for

Всем доброго времени суток!
Ввожу 1 - выдает 9, ввожу 3 - выдает 14...Подскажите, пожалуйста, - где допущена ошибка? Заранее благодарю за помощь!

```
int n, i, sum;

scanf("%d", &n);

for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
{
    sum += i;
}
printf("n = %d; sum = %d", n, sum);
return 0;
```

Comment: `printf("n = %d; sum = %d", n, n*(n+1)/2);` - и не нужно никакой `sum` или цикла.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в том, что переменная `sum` не инициализирована никаким значением и может содержать что попало. Исправить легко: `int sum = 0;`